# Setting up sound on a LTSP server

Tags: ltsp

I've got a Fedora 13 server setup and running successfully.  Unfortunately I'm having issues making sure the clients can hear sound.

I've installed the necessary alsa packages but I'm not having any luck.

```
# rpm -qa | grep alsa
alsa-oss-1.0.17-4.fc12.x86_64
alsa-lib-1.0.23-1.fc13.x86_64
alsa-utils-1.0.23-3.fc13.x86_64
alsa-oss-libs-1.0.17-4.fc12.x86_64
alsa-plugins-pulseaudio-1.0.22-1.fc13.x86_64
```

Any idea what I should be looking at?

Comment: Any particular reason you're using 64-bit on an old Fedora release that was End of Life'd last June? You'd be far better off with a more recent release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had quite a few problems with 64-bit LTSP installations prior to 2010. And considering that you're looking to run an old, in fact now-unsupported, version of Fedora, I'd consider moving up to a more recent release on 64-bit or dropping to a 32-bit install with PAE.

Our 32-bit Ubuntu deployments of LTSP have always been fantastic right out of the box (except for a generation of Intel video on Dells), but the Fedora stuff has always been flaky for us running a dozen or so SuperMicro installations.